# Camel Client for netty tcp port using

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, netty, jbossfuse

i am trying consume data from the server using port 7000. For which i have written the following camel endpoint.

```
from("netty:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false&"
        +"encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder").to("bean:echoService");
```

But this is not working. I keep getting bind exception. what i understood is that the above route trying to host server on port 7000.I need to write a client to consume data from 7000. Please provide me reference to write the client to consume data from a port using camel netty end point.

Comment: Ok but how will your client get triggered?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do.Are you listening on port 7000 for connections from a client, or are you trying to connect to a service that is listening on port 7000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you're asking.  But if you're using Camel 2.15 or greater the option of `clientMode`, [found in small print here](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html), may be of use to you.

It'll prevent the pesky bind exception.

Also from what I understand, plain old `netty` is deprecated and you should be using `netty4`.

So your route should look something like:

```
from("netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false&"
    +"encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder&clientMode=true").to("bean:echoService");
```

Comment: Thanks much for your response. I am trying to listen on port 7000. A process/server running on port 7000. i am trying to consume the data produced by port 7000. Basically client to receive data from 7000. I read about the clientMode=true.I think i tried with old version of camel .I will try with 2.15 along with netty4.

Comment: its working with below entry.from("netty:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false&"
       +"encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder&clientMode=true").to("bean:echoService");

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! I'd still suggest using `netty4` instead of `netty` due to the fact `netty` is deprecated though!